# Questions about double particles 「は」in a same sentence and using comma

Tags: syntax, particle-は, manga

Here is the full sentence.

負けず嫌いで、しかも勇敢な矢吹丈**は**、ナイフで刺すとか拳銃で撃つといった、卑怯なリヴェンジ**は**何も考えませんでした。

1. I guess that the first one would be the actual subject marker and the whole sentence would roughly be translated like followings:

'Yabuki Joe who is brave and hate to lose did not know how to revenge the unfairness he got which feel as if stabbing with a knife or shooting with a pistol.'

If I am correct in the translation as above, what is the purpose to put the second 「は」after the word 「リヴェンジ」?

2. Is it still grammatically correct if I remove all commas in the sentence? Mostly conversational bubbles found in the manga I have been reading never use it but the sentence above came from the review section written in the end of the manga.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the first は is the main topic, and the second is the typical "contrastive" は often found with negative predicates -- very nearly a collocation of sorts. And I suppose you could remove the commas without changing the meaning at all here, but it would hinder readability a great deal. I imagine the manga version might use line breaks instead of commas?

As for your translation, it's almost there, but slightly off meaning-wise w.r.t 考える.

> 負けず嫌いで、しかも勇敢な矢吹丈は、ナイフで刺すとか拳銃で撃つといった、卑怯なリベンジは何も考えませんでした。
>   Yabuki Joe, a sore loser, and / but what's more a brave man, didn't for even a moment consider getting some sort of cowardly / low payback like stabbing or shooting .